# Spring JPA Repository With Super Class as Type

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Apologies in advanced if this question is a duplicate but I did my fair effort of looking for an answer to this question and couldn't find it anywhere.

The problem I have is that I want to use the `findAll()` method declared in the JPA Repository Interface to be able to retrieve all the entries in a certain table.

The interface that implements JPA Repository **(see code below)** I have, has Type Class a Super Class **(Person)** of which User, Manager and Administrator extend. These sub classes are annotated with different @Table arguments as to make the USERs go the users table, etc...

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
    Person deleteByUsernameAndEmail(String username, String email);
    Person deleteByEmail(String email);
    Person deleteByUsername(String username);
}
```

Now I have several questions which are:

- How do I make my `findAll()` method return all the entries of a certain table (lets say the table users)?
- Do I create three different interfaces, each one with a different Type Class (User, Manager, Administrator) or this is a bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good practice to separate each type into different interfaces. If you need logic that operates on each, you can create custom interfaces, the implementations to those and extends your repository interface with the custom interface. Spring can automatically recognize the implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and for clarifying things for me. That was an option I knew I could take but I wanted to confirm that it's a good practice to have 1 interface per type. Thank you very much for your help @zlaval

Comment: maybe this helps: https://blog.netgloo.com/2014/12/18/handling-entities-inheritance-with-spring-data-jpa/